# Filter queries inside templates django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-template-filters

models:

```
class Level(models.Model):
 number = models.IntegerField()
 badge = models.ImageField()
 locked_badge = models.ImageField()
 timestamp = 
 models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,blank=True, 
 null=True)
 unlock = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="A")

 def __str__(self):
    return str(self.number)
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('student:level-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ToDo(models.Model):
 level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 description = models.TextField()
 timestamp = 
 models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,blank=True, 
 null=True)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Task(models.Model):
 level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 content = models.TextField()
 timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
 datestamp = models.DateField( auto_now=True)
 like = 
 models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes',blank=True)
 is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
 def __str__(self):
    return self.title

 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('student:dashboard')
 objects = PostManager()

 @property
 def comments(self):
    instance = self
    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
    return qs

 @property
 def get_content_type(self):
    instance = self
    content_type = 
 ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
    return content_type
```

Template:

```
 {% for level in levels %}
 {% if tasks.filter(student=student,level=level).count == 
   todos.filter(level=level).count %}
 <li>
 <a href="javascript:;"><img src="{{ level.badge.url }}" alt="" /></a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                         <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="{{ 
 level.locked_badge.url }}" alt="" /></a>
                        </li>
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

sample view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def StudentPublicProfile(request,pk=None):
 student = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

 levels = Level.objects.all()

 todos=ToDo.objects.all()

 tasks=Task.objects.all()

 context={
    'student': student,
    'levels' : levels,
    'tasks' : tasks,
    'todos' : todos,
 }



 return render(request, 'student_public_profile2.html', context)
```

This might need a little explanation. I have 3 models- Level Todo and Task. Each level contains many todos.When a todo is completed,ie,when a todo form is submitted,It gets saved in the Task model.The form uses model form,so basically task is the set of completed todos of the user of a level. I want to display badges for the levels based on a condition which is : If all the todos of a level is completed,it should display one type of badge,if not it should display a locked badge!How do i go about this?

I came accross template tags..I make my custom tags like this:

```
 @register.filter
 def completed(tasks,student, level):
  return tasks.filter(student=student,level=level).count()


 @register.filter
 def alltodos(todo, level):
    return todo.filter(level=level).count()
```

How to call function from template for this to work correctly?

```
    {% for level in levels %}
    {% if tasks|completed:tasks,student,level == 
      todos|alltodos:todos,level %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="{{ 
     level.badge.url }}" alt="" /></a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                         <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="{{ 
       level.locked_badge.url }}" alt="" /></a>
                        </li>
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please *don't* filter in the template. Django templates have deliberately been restricted to make this "not easy". Such logic belngs in the *view*, not in the *template*.

Comment: Ok but how do i implement this in the view  since i need to query based on the level @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Can you please help me write the view?  @dfundako

Comment: i have edited my question.How to pass the template tag arguments correctly ? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: i have edited my question.How to pass the template tag arguments correctly ?  @dfundako